# Plotting in python: My arrays have same dimensions but interpreter complains that they are not

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am a python newbie; trying to migrate from matlab. But I get the following error on the code below: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

I dont seem to see why as my arrays both have 101 elements:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import pylab as py
import matplotlib as plt
k=1
y=[None]*101
#print(y)
for i in sc.arange(0.0,10,0.1):
    y[k]=np.log(i)
    #print(y[k])
    k=k+1


j=sc.arange(0.0,10,0.1)
#y=np.array(y)
#j=np.array(j)
py.plot(y,j)
py.show()
```

Comment: "I dont seem to see why as my arrays both have 101 elements:" <- prove it.  :-)  Where is your `print(len(y), len(j))` to confirm your guess?

Comment: Well, you got me. len(j) is 100 while len(y) is 101. But that brings me to another question -- I use sc.arange(0.0,10.0.1) to produce both j and y (as u can see in the for loop and the line of code just before the plot function). I thought they should be the same length if the counter was to start from 0 to 10 in steps of 0.1. Why are they not?

Comment: I noticed that if i replaced the line y[k]=np.log(i) with the line y[k]=sc.log(i), my code above would still work. Does this mean that the numpy and scipy libraries share the same functions? -- In this case they both seem to have log.

Comment: @Minaj when scipy is imported it also imports most numpy functions into its own namespace, so calling from `sc` will usually work. However, most code I have seen makes the call from the numpy namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from some fundamental differences between Matlab and numpy/scipy.

Firstly, arrays in python are indexed from 0, as opposed to 1 in Matlab. Therefore, the variable `k` should start from 0.

The other issue here is that you have assumed the `arange(0, 10, 0.1)` call will produce the same 101-length output as Matlab. If you refer to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for `numpy.arange`, you will see that unlike Matlab, `numpy.arange` will not include the upper range value in the output.

> *Values are generated within the **half-open interval [start, stop)** (in other words, the interval including start **but excluding stop**)*

I suggest taking a look at [this site](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) to better understand the differences between the two languages.

Comment: Thanks @user3419537 for the thorough response.